# R mutate function with two tables

Tags: r

I'm beginner with R and I'm trying do a merge with mutate but is not running right.

I have two tables and  I need put a flag when there is the similar id

I tried:

```
resultado <- inclusos  %>% 
  mutate (flag_erro_cv = ifelse(ID_CNDO == user_erro$ID_USRO,1,0))
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Hi! You'll have more success on stackoverflow. if you provide some sample data. Do you want to do something like `flag_erro_cv = 1 * (ID_CNDO %in% user_erro$ID_USRO)`?

Comment: Thannnnks. now I could to get the results